# How to load a BigQuery table from a file in GCS Bucket using Airflow?

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am new to Airflow, and I am wondering, how do I load a file from a GCS Bucket to BigQuery?

So far, I have managed to do BigQuery to GCS Bucket:

```
bq_recent_questions_query = bigquery_operator.BigQueryOperator(
    task_id='bq_recent_questions_query',
    sql="""
    SELECT owner_display_name, title, view_count
    FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions`
    WHERE creation_date < CAST('{max_date}' AS TIMESTAMP)
        AND creation_date >= CAST('{min_date}' AS TIMESTAMP)
    ORDER BY view_count DESC
    LIMIT 100
    """.format(max_date=max_query_date, min_date=min_query_date),
    use_legacy_sql=False,
    destination_dataset_table=bq_recent_questions_table_id)

# Export query result to Cloud Storage.
export_questions_to_gcs = bigquery_to_gcs.BigQueryToCloudStorageOperator(
    task_id='export_recent_questions_to_gcs',
    source_project_dataset_table=bq_recent_questions_table_id,
    destination_cloud_storage_uris=[output_file],
    export_format='CSV')
```

Can someone help me to modify my current code, so I can load a file from a GCS Bucket and load it to BigQuery?

Comment: There is a operator already created to perform that action, see the below links for an example and module documentation
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/cloud/gcs.html#gcstobigqueryoperator

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/gcs_to_bigquery/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirement, you can use  [GCSToBigQueryOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/gcs_to_bigquery/index.html) which is an operator in airflow to transfer files from Cloud Storage to BigQuery.For more information, check this [link](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/gcs_to_bigquery.py). You can try the below code.

**gcs_to_bq_operator.py**

```
import os
from airflow import DAG
from airflow import models
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.bigquery import (
    BigQueryCreateEmptyDatasetOperator,
    BigQueryDeleteDatasetOperator,
)
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.gcs_to_bigquery import GCSToBigQueryOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

DATASET_NAME = os.environ.get("GCP_DATASET_NAME", 'new-dataset')
TABLE_NAME = os.environ.get("GCP_TABLE_NAME", 'Country')

dag = models.DAG(
    dag_id='gcs_to_bq_operator',
    start_date=days_ago(2),
    schedule_interval='@once',
    tags=['example'],
)

create_test_dataset = BigQueryCreateEmptyDatasetOperator(
    task_id='create_airflow_test_dataset', dataset_id=DATASET_NAME, dag=dag
)

# [START howto_operator_gcs_to_bigquery]
load_csv = GCSToBigQueryOperator(
    task_id='gcs_to_bigquery_example',
    bucket='sample-bucket',
    source_objects=['cloud storage URI'],
    destination_project_dataset_table=f"{DATASET_NAME}.{TABLE_NAME}",
    schema_fields=[
        {'name': 'Year', 'type': 'INTEGER', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
        {'name': 'Country', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
        {'name': 'number', 'type': 'INTEGER', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
        {'name': 'result', 'type': 'INTEGER', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'}
    ],
    write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
    dag=dag,
)
```

Comment: Yes, thanks! That is exactly what I needed. One question - in my schema, if I have a column called ```DATE```, how would I store the current date of when the data gets inserted into that column?

Comment: Hi @user17328160, You can use either [`DATE`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#date_type) or [`DATETIME`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#datetime_type) for storing date.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused about the question, from your title it looks like you want to create a Bigquery table from a file in GCS. I'm assuming this in my answer.

You can leverage the `load_file` operator from [Astro SDK](https://pypi.org/project/astro-sdk-python/) which allows rapid and clean development of {Extract, Load, Transform} workflows using Python and SQL, powered by Apache Airflow.

`load_file` operator can help you transfer data between Blob-storages(Azure, GCS, S3 - [Supported locations](https://astro-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/1.5.0/supported_file.html)), File servers(SFTP, FTP) and local filesystem to Databases(Bigquery, Redshift, Snowflake, SQlite, Postgres, duckDB, MSSQL...) for a complete list of supported Databases check - [Supported Databases](https://astro-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/1.5.0/supported_databases.html). In some cases you can even optimize the transfer by using a [native path](https://astro-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/1.5.0/guides/concepts.html#how-load-file-works) which is very useful for larger files(~in >= GBs)

Here is an example -

```
 from datetime import datetime

 from airflow.models import DAG

 from astro import sql as aql
 from astro.files import File
 from astro.table import Metadata, Table

 default_args = {
    "owner": "airflow",
    "retries": 1,
    "retry_delay": 0,
 }

 dag = DAG(
     dag_id="example_load_file",
     start_date=datetime(2019, 1, 1),
     max_active_runs=3,
     schedule_interval=None,
     default_args=default_args,
     catchup=False,
 )
 
 @aql.run_raw_sql(handler=handle_result)
 def filter_table(table: Table):
    return """SELECT owner_display_name, title, view_count
           FROM {{table}}
           WHERE creation_date < CAST('{max_date}' AS TIMESTAMP)
           AND creation_date >= CAST('{min_date}' AS TIMESTAMP)
           ORDER BY view_count DESC
           LIMIT 100"""

 with dag:
    test_table = aql.load_file(
        input_file=File("gcs://replace_me/replace_me.csv", conn_id="gcs_conn"),
        output_table=Table(conn_id="bigquery_conn")
    )
    filter_table(test_table)
```

Please look into the [documentation](https://astro-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/1.5.0/astro/sql/operators/load_file.html) for further help.